# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when using #table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this variable

```
DECLARE @Caracteristiques TABLE
      (
            EnsembleImmobilierId int,
            ImmobilierId      int,
            BatimentId        int,
            Code              varchar(5),
            Valeur                  varchar(40)
      )
```

Querying it with this

```
SELECT      CONVERT(decimal(15,4), ISNULL(C.Valeur, 0))
FROM  @Caracteristiques C
```

Everything seems fine. 
If for instence, I'm changing the variable table for a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #Caracteristiques 
      (
            EnsembleImmobilierId int,
            ImmobilierId      int,
            BatimentId        int,
            Code              varchar(5),
            Valeur                  varchar(40)
      )
```

I'm getting this

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure IvpCalculation, Line 140
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

How can we explain it?

Comment: "Everything seems fine" - well, did you insert the same data into both tables? I suspect not.

Comment: I found my problem, the execution path was different for both cases and then the filter condition of the where was executed in a different order causing the convert to try converting characters... I ommited the where of the query in the question, my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem in your query; most probably there is string value like "abcde" in your column `Valeur` which is not convertible to decimal and hence it's throwing that error.

I have tried the same and it's works fine if your `valeur` column have value like "12345"; even if you cast like `cast(isnull(Valeur,'') as decimal(15,4))`.  see the below fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32a5b/3

Comment: I found my problem, the execution path was different for both cases and then the filter condition of the where was executed in a different order causing the convert to try converting characters...  I ommited the where of the query in the question, my bad...